# PC reboots randomly while powered on

Tags: lubuntu, reboot

I have an old machine and a new machine, I just installed Lubuntu on the old one because I tried to transition from Lubuntu but Puppy Linux but went back right after because Puppy Linux wasn't suitable for me, even though it had no problem. Before installing Puppy Linux, Lubuntu ran with no problems, and before that I had to re-install Lubuntu because it kept prompting me and waiting for direct user input on boot to "Press S to skip mounting or Press M for Manual recovery.". And before that I had a Lubuntu-Zorin dual-boot, but the PC was too slow for Zorin, so I backed up and went fresh. Now, with the latest Iteration the PC reboots randomly as if the command "Reboot" was invoked at random, I think around 15 minutes of uptime, whether idle or active. Running `last reboot` says this:

> reboot   system boot  3.13.0-43-generi Sun Dec 28 20:23 - 20:25  (00:01)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-43-generi Sun Dec 28 20:09 - 20:10  (00:01)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-43-generi Sun Dec 28 20:07 - 20:08  (00:00)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-43-generi Sun Dec 28 18:56 - 18:57  (00:00)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-43-generi Sun Dec 28 18:35 - 18:56  (00:20)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-43-generi Sun Dec 28 16:20 - 18:34  (02:14)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-43-generi Sun Dec 28 15:55 - 16:15  (00:20)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-43-generi Sun Dec 28 15:44 - 15:54  (00:09)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-43-generi Sun Dec 28 14:41 - 15:44  (01:02)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-43-generi Sun Dec 28 13:40 - 14:40  (01:00)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-43-generi Sun Dec 28 13:21 - 13:22  (00:00)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-43-generi Sun Dec 28 13:20 - 13:20  (00:00)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-43-generi Sun Dec 28 12:17 - 13:20  (01:02)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-24-generi Sat Dec 27 22:04 - 12:16  (14:11)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-24-generi Sat Dec 27 09:30 - 22:02  (12:31)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-24-generi Sat Dec 27 09:28 - 09:29  (00:00)
>
> wtmp begins Sat Dec 27 09:28:54 2014

(The first two of the last three are the reboots at random, anything less then 3 minutes was me powering off or on the machine so I can plug stuff in, but I can't plug stuff in without moving it, and I power it off because I once moved a machine and it froze.)

Comment: So many words, so little information.

Comment: @fleamour In general, some install iterations had problems, but this PC reboots on it's own around 15 minutes after it is turned on with this iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing hardware problems.

Your Lubuntu problem *"Press S to skip mounting or Press M for Manual recovery."* could have been from corrupted filesystems. And random reboots could be an indication of bad RAM too.

I had a laptop with bad RAM that would reboot just like that, after 20-40 minutes, the RAM was physically dirty & I think even had corroded contacts, after a while it wouldn't work at all with that RAM

Comment: That problem was fixed by a re-install, the current install did not do that and that install didn't have random reboots. Also, the PC's from 2004 and it has 1 GB RAM.